# How to shorten the code with the select list ? Spring HTML

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I wonder how I can shorten the code. I have a select list written in HTML. This is a list of airports. However, it is very long. Too long.

```html
<body> <form action="#" th:action="@{/connect}" th:object="${FlightDTO}" method="post">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">

            <h2>Destination</h2>
            <select name="myselect" id="myselect"     th:field="*{departure}"   >
                <option value="AALAalesund">Aalborg</option>
                <option value="ZID">Aarhus</option>
                <option value="AAR">Aarhus</option>
                <option value="JEG">Aasiaat</option>
                <option value="ABD">Abadan</option>
    ... etc.
```

Please help me .

Comment: Where do you want to shorten it? *why* do you want to shorten it?

Comment: A database. Or you could do static page generation but the HTML would still be like that on client-side.

Comment: Boy, I'd re-consider this UX design altogether.  Do you want a user to scroll through a list of hundreds of airports?  One solution could be an autocomplete input field.  Pick an airline website for an example.

Answer (score 0):

you add add airports to database.

Create Airport java Class

`Airport Class`:

```
public class Airport {

    private String name;
    private String value;


    // setter and getter ...

}
```

and generate list of airports `List<Airport>` and add to `model`

```
model.addAttribute("airports", List<Airport> );
```

and then in html page you can use this:

```
<option th:each="items : ${airports}" 
        th:value="${items.value}"
        th:text="${items.name}">
</option>
```